# How to insert newLine Between Text

Tags: java, string

I have created an object(**new1**) which contains the following text

**E-Mail: custrelations@abc.comConfirmation Number (PNR):H246FY**

The output should be displayed in two seperate line as follow:

**E-Mail: custrelations@spicejet.com**

**Confirmation Number (PNR):H246FY**

Created the following logic, but it is not taking ".com" while printing the output

**

```
String[] inputSplitNewLine =new1.split(".com");
for(int i=0;i<inputSplitNewLine.length;i++){ 
     System.out.println(inputSplitNewLine[i]);
 }
```

**

Comment: You don't want to split on `.com`, you want to split after it.  Try using `String#indexOf` and `String#substring` instead

Comment: when the line itself is getting prepared by you then why don't you add new line character or some variable using which you can split.

Comment: Please note that `split` takes a *regex* and **not** a regular String. `.` is a special character and has a special meaning in regex. You should quote it and do: `.split("\\.com");`.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

For this specific `String` you can use [`#replace`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#replace%28java.lang.CharSequence,%20java.lang.CharSequence%29) method.

```
  String str="E-Mail: custrelations@abc.comConfirmation Number (PNR):H246FY";
  str=str.replace(".com", ".com\n");
  //str=str.replace(".com", ".com\r\n");
  System.out.println(str);
```

---

**OUTPUT**

```
E-Mail: custrelations@abc.com
Confirmation Number (PNR):H246FY
```

---

*Note*:`\r\n` should be used for windows as well instead of just `\n` pointed out by [`Scary Wombat`](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2310289/scary-wombat) as well.

Answer (score 1):

You can do it using indexOf + substring to get the position of the `.com`.

**sample:**

```
String s = "E-Mail: custrelations@abc.comConfirmation Number (PNR):H246FY";
System.out.println(s.substring(0, s.indexOf(".com") + 4));
System.out.println(s.substring(s.indexOf(".com") + 4, s.length()));
```

**result:**

```
E-Mail: custrelations@abc.com
Confirmation Number (PNR):H246FY
```

You can also use the `StringBuffer` insert method

```
StringBuffer s = new StringBuffer("E-Mail: custrelations@abc.comConfirmation Number (PNR):H246FY");
System.out.println(s.insert(s.indexOf(".com") + 4, "\n"));
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this code using [String#indexOf()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#indexOf(int)) function to get index of `.com` and substring according to it  :

```
int inputSplitNewLine = new1.indexOf(".com");
String s1 = new1.substring(0, inputSplitNewLine + 4);
String s2 = new1.substring(inputSplitNewLine + 4);
System.out.println(s1);
System.out.println(s2);
```

OutPut :

```
E-Mail: custrelations@abc.com
Confirmation Number (PNR):H246FY
```

Answer (score 1):

According to the [API](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#split(java.lang.String)), the .split(...) method in the String class splits strings **around** the regex given as an argument. If you look at the examples the API gives, it removes the characters that match when splitting the string.

Answer (score 1):

Do it like this:

```
String s = "E-Mail: custrelations@abc.comConfirmation Number (PNR):H246FY";
int index = s.indexOf(".com");
System.out.println(s.substring(0, index + ".com".length()));
System.out.println(s.substring(index + ".com".length()));
```

or

```
System.out.println(s.replaceFirst(".com", ".com\n"));
```

Answer (score 0):

```
String str = "E-Mail: custrelations@abc.comConfirmation Number (PNR):H246FY";
str = str.replace(".com", ".com%n") // Becomes: E-Mail: custrelations@abc.com%nConfirmation Number (PNR):H246FY
// For OS independent Line Seperator let String.format do it
str = String.format(str); // Replaces %n to OS Line separator
System.out.println(str);
```

**Output:**

```
E-Mail: custrelations@abc.com
Confirmation Number (PNR):H246FY
```